# Pulling Images from RSS Feed

Tags: c#, vb.net, rss

I am developing a background wallpaper changer for Windows. I am looking into pulling images from RSS feeds. As how they are displayed from feed to feed changes, I am currently pulling the page as text and searching for text such as `"<img src="...` and others. Obviously this is not a viable option, how else could I complete this?

Comment: Couldn't you use whatever you are using to read the RSS feed to read images too?

Comment: I could but only a few of the RSS feeds I want to use actually define an image element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would think you would need to do that to get the partial image URL, and then append the baes URL from the original server (unless the URL in the RSS feed is the full URL to the image).

Then, you can download it with something like: http://forums.asp.net/t/1224738.aspx but instead of using Response.OutputStream, use the stream to a file to save it to the server.

And that will write image files to your machine...

HTH.